# Coff2Omf generate error: reading new style import record

Tags: static-libraries, c++builder, visual-studio-express, file-conversion, omf2coff

I have compiled the libvorbis static library with Visual Studio Express 2012, no errors there.
Then I convert the .lib file with `coff2omf.exe` so I can link it with C++ Builder XE7.

```
coff2omf.exe libvorbis_static.lib libvorbis.lib
```

But I get the following error (from coff2omf.exe):

```
ERROR: COFF error: libvorbis_static.lib
  (coffread.cpp, 1561) : reading new style import record
```

I use coff2omf.exe version 1.2.0 included with C++ Builder XE7.
Is there a setting in Visual Studio Express 2012 project I can use to get an "older" coff header?
I'm not proficient with the Visual studio environment and don't know all the possible settings...

Comment: Have you tried compiling libvorbis in C++Builder instead of VisualStudio? Assuming it does not have a bpr/cproj file, have you tried creating one? C++Builder has a project template for creating static libraries.

Comment: I'm trying right now, but there are tons of compiler errors. I'm trying to resolve these now...

Comment: I managed to compile now... But back to the original question; Is Coff2Omf outdated? Is there a newer version that can deal with the new Coff format?